# New Firebase Facebook login

Tags: firebase, swift2, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I'm trying to make a Facebook login with the new Firebase platform.

this is the code for the facebook login

```
let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()
    facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self) { (result, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print("error is \(error)")
        } else {
            let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString

            let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(accessToken)

            AUTH?.signInWithCredential(credential, completion: { (user, error) -> Void in

                if error != nil {
                    print("error is \(error)")
                } else {
                    print(user)
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(user?.uid, forKey: KEY_UID)
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(SEGUE_LOGGEDIN, sender: nil)
                }
            })
        }
```

and this is the error code i get

> Optional(Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo={error_name=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSUnderlyingError=0x79f082b0 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={type = immutable dict, count = 3,
>   entries =>
>
> 0 : {contents = "errors"} = {type = immutable, count = 1, values = (
>
> 0 : {type = immutable dict, count = 3,
>   entries =>
>
> 0 : {contents = "reason"} = {contents = "invalid"}
>
> 1 : {contents = "message"} = {contents = "Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook: {"error":{"message":"Invalid OAuth access token signature.","type":"OAuthException","code":190,"fbtrace_id":"BrewfOSy/fH"}}"}
>
> 2 : {contents = "domain"} = {contents = "global"}
>   }
>
> )}
>
> 1 : {contents = "code"} = {value = +400, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}
>
> 2 : {contents = "message"} = {contents = "Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook: {"error":{"message":"Invalid OAuth access token signature.","type":"OAuthException","code":190,"fbtrace_id":"BrewfOSy/fH"}}"}
>
> }
>
> }}, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.})

Comment: having a similar problem, has this been resolved?

Comment: Also running into this issue with google sign in after trying to upgrade to Firebase 3.2

Comment: In error item 2 it refers the OAuth protocol. Did you enable the OAuth redirect on facebook developer page?

Comment: @ByteArtisan yes i did

Comment: Anyone figure this out?

Comment: Check your status in /review-status/. App should be active.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you enable Facebook authentication in your firebase console.

Make sure you enter the correct FACEBOOK App ID and App Secret in the firebase console. (Not your XCode App ID)

Answer (score -4):

// Auth with Firebase

FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in

Also returns the same error code "FIRAuthErrorDomain" when I'm using GoogleSignIn.
There are no description of the "FIRAuthErrorDomain" in the doc.