# Firebase: login error

Tags: ios, error-handling, firebase, firebase-authentication

**EDIT:** I found [a similar question specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37356395/new-firebase-facebook-login) to the Facebook login. I am using email authentication but the problem / solution may be the same.

---

I am using the Firebase demo example class **SignInViewController** and it works well on the demo project. However when I try to integrate it on my own project it gives me the following error:

> UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x14704d4b0 {Error
>   Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={type = immutable dict, count = 3, entries
>   =>    0 : {contents = "message"} = {contents = "INVALID_EMAIL"}   1 :
>   errors = {type = immutable, count =
>   1, values = (     0 : {type =
>   immutable dict, count = 3, entries =>     0 : reason = invalid    1 :
>   message = {contents =
>   "INVALID_EMAIL"}  2 : domain = global }
>
> )}    2 : code = {value =
>   +400, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type} } }}, error_name=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal
>   error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more
>   information.}

I enabled the Email login method on the console for the app.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Without seeing the minimal code with (preferably hard-coded) values you are using, it'll be hard to say what's going on.

Comment: I had a slightly variation of this error. Found a several posts with variants of this error. The thing that varies is the contents property, and in your case says INVALID_MAIL. Sure the e-mail valid? in my case contents was absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

Check your settings on dev.facebook in "Login with Facebook" -> "Settings" and paste correct OAuth redirect URIs from Firebase to
"Valid OAuth redirect URIs" field. Next enable your Facebook app (should be green). In code paste this:

```
    func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
    if error != nil {
        self.showAlert(msg: AlertMessages.facebookLoginError)
        return
    }
    if !result.isCancelled {

        let token = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
        let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(token)
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                UserAuthManager.sharedInstance.logoutFromFacebook()

                if let errCode = FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: error.code) { // error
                }
                return
            }
            self.userDidSignedIn()
            //Logged with FB!
        }
    }
}
```

Remeber to set FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also enable sign in with email/password in your Firebase console.

Firebase console -> Authentication -> Sign-in method -> **Enable** provider Email/Password.

[image: toggle in firebase]